# Coequalizers are quotient maps

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Is it possible to show that every coequalizer in the category of Hausdorff spaces is a quotient map directly from the universal property of a coequalizer and without use of the set-theoretical construction of the standard-coequalizer?

More precisely, is there a replacement for $h_U$ in the following proof sketch such that $h_U$s codomain is a Hausdorff space?

All maps hereinafter shall be continuous functions, that is **TOP**-arrows.

**Problem:**
Let $e:B\to E$ be a coequalizer for the arrows $f_1,f_2:A\to B$. $e$ is a quotient map, i.e. $\forall U \subseteq E: e^{-1}(U) \text{ open in } B\leftrightarrow U \text{ open in } E$

**Proof:** Let $U\subseteq E$ such that $e^{-1}(U)$ is open in $B$. I aim for $U$ to be open in $E$.
To that end I define a map $h_U:B\to D$, where $D$ is $U$ with a new point $0$ adjoint to it in an indiscrete fashion, that is the topology of $D=\mathcal{O}_E(U) \cup \{U,U\cup\{0\}\}$, where $\mathcal{O}_E(U)$ is the subspace topology of $U$ regarded as a subspace of $E$.

I want $h_U$ to be a sort of indicator function for $e^{-1}(U)$ so I set 
$h_U(x) = \begin{cases}e(x) & x\in e^{-1}(U) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Now according to my calculations $h_U\circ f_1 = h_U\circ f_2$ and the universal property of the coequalizer $e$ yields an arrow $j_U:E\to D$ with $h_U = j_U\circ e$ which renders $U=j_U^{-1}(U)$ open.

**Background:** I want to show that every coequalizer is a quotient map in the context of a set theory which has a notion of open sets, but is not powerful enough to grant me standard-coequalizers.

Comment: I fixed a couple of typos, but besides that I have two questions. (a) Since you added 0 "in an indiscrete fashion", your $D$ isn't a Hausdorff space. But then how can you apply the coequalizer condition for **Hausdorff**? (b) I don't see why $h_U\circ f_1=h_U\circ f_2$. What prevents having an $a\in A$ for which $f_1(a)\in e^{-1}(U)$ and $f_2(a)\not\in e^{-1}(U)$, in which case $h_U(f_1(a))\neq 0$ and $h_U(f_2(a))=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if this is good enough for your purposes (I'm not sure what you mean by avoiding "standard-coequalizers"), but here's one thing you can do.  Suppose you have a coequalizer $e:B\to E$ of arrows $f_1,f_2:A\to B$.  Consider the space $E'$ which has the same underlying set as $E$ but the quotient topology: that is, $U\subseteq E'$ is open iff $e^{-1}(U)$ is open in $B$.  Since $e$ is continuous, this topology is fine than the topology on $E$, so $E'$ is Hausdorff.  We can then factor $e$ as a composition $B\stackrel{e'}{\to} E'\stackrel{i}{\to} E$ where $i$ is the identity map on on the underlying sets.  We then have $e'f_1=e'f_2$, so by the universal property there is a unique $j:E\to E'$ such that $je=e'$.  It is then clear that $j$ must be the identity on the underlying sets and so it is an inverse for $i$, and so $E=E'$.

In other words, you can get a $D$ that works for all open subsets $U$ at once by just taking $D$ to be $E$ with the quotient topology.